# Function for all rows in a data frame R

Tags: r

I have a question,

I dispose of a data frame:

```
            MInc      t0.01       t0.1         t0.2       t0.5       t0.8
A4GALT 0.1605681 0.16056814 0.27212265 0.3490585760 0.07486080         NA
AAAS   0.2992754 0.04794018 0.09057540 0.0001127665         NA         NA
AADAC  0.3027883 0.30278830 0.30278830 0.3027883033 0.30278830 0.28501358
AASS   0.1307001 0.12665125 0.12665125 0.1266512501 0.12665125 0.21474030
AATF   0.1453662 0.09392991         NA           NA         NA         NA
AATK   0.2567986 0.11338287 0.11338287 0.1133828663 0.11338287 0.11093412
ABCA8  0.1577148 0.07236169 0.07236169 0.1420553677 0.06185948 0.04529619
ABCB10 0.1437084 0.04794018         NA           NA         NA         NA
ABCB8  0.1022297 0.05264867         NA           NA         NA         NA
ABCC8  0.1577148 0.13209778 0.13209778 0.1320977809 0.07740797         NA
ABCD2  0.1453662 0.26370072 0.23850217 0.0572556220         NA         NA
ABCG2  0.1453662 0.08066152 0.04904863 0.0452961926 0.04529619         NA
ABHD12 0.1062786 0.13495108         NA           NA         NA         NA
```

I'm searching for a commands for divide the minimum value in each row (omitting the first column) between the corresponding value in the first column for this row.

The output have to be a data frame with one column containing this value for each row. For example, for the first row of my data, the computation would be this:

```
A4GALT 0.07486080/0.1605681 = 0.4662246.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmin` to get the minimum value per row.  If you need to divide the 'min' value for each `row` with all the columns of dataset, we can replicate the the results obtained with `pmin`.  One option is indexing with `row(df1)` and divide by 'df1'.

```
do.call(pmin, c(df1[-1], na.rm=TRUE))[row(df1)]/df1
```

Or if you need this only for the 1st column, we divide by the subset of 'df1' (with the option `drop=FALSE` to avoid it getting converted to `vector`).

```
 do.call(pmin, c(df1[-1], na.rm=TRUE))/df1[,1,drop=FALSE] 
 #                 MInc
 #  A4GALT 0.4662246112
 #  AAAS   0.0003767984
 #  AADAC  0.9412965428
 #  AASS   0.9690218294
 #  AATF   0.6461605930
 #  AATK   0.4319888037
 #  ABCA8  0.2872031667
 #  ABCB10 0.3335934434
 #  ABCB8  0.5150036633
 #  ABCC8  0.4908098035
 #  ABCD2  0.3938716290
 #  ABCG2  0.3116005646
 #  ABHD12 1.2697860152
```

NOTE: I used `df1[-1]` as the OP mentioned about omitting the first column.  But if the OP assumed omitting the rownames, the code would be

```
   do.call(pmin, c(df1, na.rm=TRUE))/df1[,1,drop=FALSE]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(238)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(5000*5000), ncol=5000)
df2 <- as.data.frame(m1)
jalapic <- function() apply(m1[,-1], 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)/m1[,1]
thomas <- function() rowMins(m1[,-1], na.rm=TRUE)/m1[,1]
akrun <- function() do.call(pmin, c(df2[,-1], na.rm=TRUE))/df2[,1]

microbenchmark(jalapic(), thomas(), akrun(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#jalapic() 2.255453 2.224805 2.088557 2.145412 2.133398 1.9793887    20   b
#thomas() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000    20  a 
# akrun() 1.248002 1.227203 1.133792 1.212745 1.174489 0.8228857    20  a
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(MInc = c(0.1605681, 0.2992754, 0.3027883, 0.1307001, 
0.1453662, 0.2567986, 0.1577148, 0.1437084, 0.1022297, 0.1577148, 
0.1453662, 0.1453662, 0.1062786), t0.01 = c(0.16056814, 0.04794018, 
0.3027883, 0.12665125, 0.09392991, 0.11338287, 0.07236169, 0.04794018, 
0.05264867, 0.13209778, 0.26370072, 0.08066152, 0.13495108), 
    t0.1 = c(0.27212265, 0.0905754, 0.3027883, 0.12665125, NA, 
    0.11338287, 0.07236169, NA, NA, 0.13209778, 0.23850217, 0.04904863, 
    NA), t0.2 = c(0.349058576, 0.0001127665, 0.3027883033, 0.1266512501, 
    NA, 0.1133828663, 0.1420553677, NA, NA, 0.1320977809, 0.057255622, 
    0.0452961926, NA), t0.5 = c(0.0748608, NA, 0.3027883, 0.12665125, 
    NA, 0.11338287, 0.06185948, NA, NA, 0.07740797, NA, 0.04529619, 
    NA), t0.8 = c(NA, NA, 0.28501358, 0.2147403, NA, 0.11093412, 
    0.04529619, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("MInc", 
"t0.01", "t0.1", "t0.2", "t0.5", "t0.8"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("A4GALT", 
"AAAS", "AADAC", "AASS", "AATF", "AATK", "ABCA8", "ABCB10", "ABCB8", 
"ABCC8", "ABCD2", "ABCG2", "ABHD12"))
```

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, I was thinking the OP meant about the row names

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
apply(df[2:6], 1, min, na.rm=T) / df[,1]

     A4GALT         AAAS        AADAC         AASS         AATF         AATK        ABCA8       ABCB10        ABCB8        ABCC8        ABCD2        ABCG2 
0.4662246112 0.0003767984 0.9412965428 0.9690218294 0.6461605930 0.4319888037 0.2872031667 0.3335934434 0.5150036633 0.4908098035 0.3938716290 0.3116005646 
      ABHD12 
1.2697860152
```

Answer (score 1):

The `matrixStats` package might be helpful here, as it is optimized for operations such as these.

```
library("matrixStats")
rowMins(as.matrix(df1[,-1]), na.rm = TRUE)/df1[,1]
#  [1] 0.4662246112 0.0003767984 0.9412965428 0.9690218294 0.6461605930
#  [6] 0.4319888037 0.2872031667 0.3335934434 0.5150036633 0.4908098035
# [11] 0.3938716290 0.3116005646 1.2697860152
```

And here's some benchmarking:

```
library("microbenchmark")
jalapic <- function(d) apply(d[,2:6], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE) / d[,1]
thomas <- function(d) rowMins(as.matrix(d[,-1]), na.rm = TRUE)/d[,1]
akrun <- function(d) do.call(pmin, list(d[,-1], na.rm = TRUE))/d[,1]
microbenchmark(jalapic(df1), akrun(df1), thomas(df1))
# Unit: microseconds
#       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  jalapic() 232.471 242.6705 260.6561 255.5640 273.4615  336.775   100
#    akrun() 521.904 555.5815 606.8519 580.0215 602.7295 2430.161   100
#   thomas() 159.727 167.0405 188.5057 175.8935 203.4120  341.393   100
```

And here's a comparable benchmark for a larger dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
df2 <- matrix(rnorm(1e5), nrow = 1000)
microbenchmark(jalapic(df2), akrun(df2), thomas(df2))
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  jalapic(df2) 1.871308 1.951365 2.049041 1.997358 2.052397 3.811125   100
#    akrun(df2) 2.400140 2.691882 3.250569 2.725560 4.373634 4.632084   100
#   thomas(df2) 1.256649 1.367110 1.623601 1.588996 1.610165 3.491672   100
```

Comment: @akrun Benchmark holds for a larger matrix, as well. See edit.

Comment: @Thomas The function for jalapic only has 2:6 columns or is it corrected?

Comment: @Thomas Based on a 5000*5000 dataset, your solution is slightly better than mine but is still in the same 'cld'